# Hibernate Criteria and HQL will go to database by default?

Tags: java, hibernate

We know the **session.get()** will go to database but **session.load()** will not. How about **Criteria** and **HQL**?

I am worrying about the synchronization between the persistent objects and the database. As I shown in [this unit test result](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1039052&p=2484039#p2484039) with the manual monitoring of the database, Hibernate's behaviors are not always as we expected or as its manual said.

So it is important to me to know if they are directly go to database to get result or they are just looking at their persistent objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will always go to the database (unless the queries are marked as Cachable, and the query cache is enabled, and the query results are in the query cache). If entities returned by the query already exist in the session, those existing entities will be returned.

Note that the test case you linked to doesn't make much sense: modifying an entity and flushing the session should be done inside a transaction.

Comment: "modifying an entity and flushing the session should be done inside a transaction." -- Then I cannot use these detached entity in my business layer because I have no control and don't know if the modification will be saved or not and don't when if it will be saved.